# "rubberband" section in footer with css only

Tags: html, css

I've seen this question asked numerous times, but have yet to see an answer.  Is there a way to replicate the behavior below using divs and css rather than a table? Would prefer no javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/6vmkreyv/7/

```
<style>
table.footer {
 width:100%;
}
td.footer-expandable {
 width:100%;
 border: 1px solid green;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: clip;
}
td.footer-fixed {
 white-space: nowrap;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
....
<table class="footer">
 <tr>
  <td class="footer-expandable">
   Expandable section.<br/>
   It should expand/collapse as necessary to fill all available space.
  </td>
  <td class="footer-fixed">
   Fixed width section.<br/>
   It should expand just enough to fit it's contents.
  </td>
</tr>
```

Part 2 of the question would be how to clip the text in the 'expandable' section so that it does not word wrap?

Comment: There is no JS being used in that example provided.

Comment: I was asking how to do the same thing using divs rather than a table.  That would offer more flexibility should the layout change somewhere down the line.

Comment: I edited my question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="right">Expand just enough to fit</div>
    <div id="left">This one will fill any remaining space before breaking down to the next line. It will not  underflow on the right side do to the right side having a 100% margin height, even if this DIV spans for several lines. It will eventually, and that can be fixed by putting a margin of more than 100%.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer #right {
    float:right;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:100%;
}
#footer #left {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/64chLqdr/1/

Note that the width of `#footer` will determine how much `margin-bottom:100%` is. They will be equal.

Comment: Quite clever there using the bottom margin, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: calc(100% - 350px)` to calculate width of div.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.dynamic {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(100% - 350px);
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fixed {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dynamic">
    Expandable section.
    <br/>It should expand/collapse as necessary to fill all available space.
  </div>
  <div class="fixed">
    Fixed width section.
    <br/>It should expand just enough to fit it's contents.
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle for responsiveness](http://jsfiddle.net/35f0nw5j/)

Comment: I like this solution, but unless I am mistaken you have to 'hardcode' the width of the fixed section in the css?  I don't think there is no easy way to account for varying widths in different footers without resorting to javascript?